# TCL - runtime error in foreach

Tags: foreach, tcl, runtime-error

Okay guys, i got weird error for tcl script.
This is working code:

```
foreach param $bucket {
if {[lindex $param 0] == "bucketState" &&\
  ([lindex $param 1] == "provisioned" ||\
  [lindex $param 1] == "Active")} {
  set activatedFlag "TRUE"
 }
}
```

And this is not:

```
foreach param $bucket {
if {[lindex $param 0] == "bucketState" &&\
  ([lindex $param 1] == "provisioned" ||\
  [lindex $param 1] == "active")} {
  set activatedFlag "TRUE"
 }
}
```

The only difference is in "active" vs "Active". O_o

Comment: Could you give the exact error message?

Comment: It's just 'Tcl error evaluating:'

Comment: Hmm, both versions are working for me...

Comment: **Both versions are syntactically valid Tcl code.** Any problems _actually_ occur elsewhere, even if they are triggered by the changes in this location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what error you're getting, but it looks fairly clear that the list element you're comparing is case sensitive. If you want to a case-insensitive search, use [string tolower](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M44) but I can't really see why you would need to do that.

```
foreach param $bucket {
if {[lindex $param 0] == "bucketState" && \
  ([lindex $param 1] == "provisioned" || \
  [string tolower [lindex $param 1]] == "active")} {
  set activatedFlag "TRUE"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thnx for advice, but that's does no help ;/

Comment: Make sure you have a space before the backslash and nothing after it. I've corrected my code above.

Comment: Well, something else must be wrong. You're not explaining the context of the error - what other code are you running, how are you running it, in what environment, what output are you getting?